# how to fit image to the same width inside TextView android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have an image stored in database as blob and i restore it as Bitmap Image and put it inside a textview 
here is my code

```
byte[]q_img=cur.getBlob(10);
Drawable qDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(q_img,0,q_img.length));
question.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,qDrawable,null);
```

this code works perfectly and show image inside textview but the problem is in some images have width larger than width of TextView and  get overflow of width
so how i can fit the width of image to the same width of textview

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works.

set `layout_width="wrap_content"` in your `XML` file

or `TextView txt= new TextView(context);
txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` using java

Comment: did you try both? Make sure you do `txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));` after the new image is set, so that the `TextView` can adapt to it